# find root of vectorised function in python

Tags: python, matlab, optimization, scipy, vectorization

I've been porting some code from matlab to python.

Part of the code finds the root of a vectorised function, which is expensive to call.

In matlab this is efficiently achieved using the [JacobPattern](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html) option. By using this option the solver is aware that the nth element of the returned vector depends only on the nth element of the argument vector.

```
    options = optimset('Algorithm','trust-region-reflective','JacobPattern',speye(lengthOfArgument));
    roots = fsolve(@VectorisedFunction, initialGuesses, options);
```

The vectorisation in matlab speeds things up by about a factor of 100 and I expect something similar could be achieved in python. I have been looking at [scipy.optimization](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) but cannot find an equivalent of JacobPattern.

So I ask: what are the best approaches to finding the root of a vectorised function in python?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly that expensive function you are talking about does, but numpy broadcasts functions to each element in an array (vectorization is done for free).

So you could just return from the expensive function if it is working on a 0 element in your sparse array.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like this would work in a general case but in this specific case my array shouldn't contain any zeros.

Comment: I thought you had a sparse array? Isn't that why you would use JacobPattern?